# How do I apply a class to an element with JavaScript in order for CSS transitions to work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a generic JavaScript code to mask an element with a div and animate it with CSS Transitions from it's original position to the center of the viewport, expanding it almost full-screen as I do so.

I already have a working script. See snippet below: (Much of the code is commented, so I hope you can understand it.)

The main steps that I follow in the script are the following:

1. Ask for an element and get it's position.
2. Create a new class that positions any given div on top of the element from step 1 (this class contains CSS Transition properties).
3. Create a new div element and assign it the class created in step 2.
4. Now apply a DIFFERENT class (which was from the begining on the css stylesheet) to the div from step 3 in order to make it transition from the one it received in the script to this one.

```js
function expand(id) {

  //I first create a style element in which I'll be able to insert a new class that I'm going to create. This new class will be used to position the future div on top of the element whose id was provided as argument of this function.
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  style.type = 'text/css';
  var style_content = "";
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  var element_properties = element.getBoundingClientRect(); //Here I get the position of the element.

  //Now I describe the new class.
  style_content += ".container_inactive {"
    style_content += "box-sizing: border-box;";
    style_content += "position:absolute;";
    style_content += "top:" + element_properties.top + "px;";
    style_content += "left:" + element_properties.left + "px;*/";
    style_content += "padding:0px;";
    style_content += "margin:0px;";
    style_content += "border:solid;";
    style_content += "border-color:black;";
    style_content += "background-color:#40efbb;";
    style_content += "height:" + element_properties.height + "px;";
    style_content += "width:" + element_properties.width + "px;";
    style_content += "transition: all 0.5s;";
    style_content += "z-index:1;";
  style_content += "}";

  style.innerHTML = style_content; //I insert the previously described class inside the <style></style> tags.

  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style); //I insert the previously created style element inside the <head></head> tags.

  //Now I create the div
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.id = "created_div";
  div.className = "container_inactive"; //Here I assign the created class to the created div
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(div); //And instert the div in the body of the document
}

//------------This is just a random divisor------------------

document.getElementById("test_button_1").onclick = function() {
  expand("test"); //I excecute the script to create the class and the div, and assigning the style to the div.

  /*With the following line I would apply a DIFFERENT class to the div (and not the one created in the previous script), in order to make it transition to it. But here is where I run into troubles.
 If uncommented, the CSS Transition won't take place.
  If excecuted later by another button, the CSS does takes place as you can see in this snippet*/
  //document.getElementById("created_div").classList.toggle("container_expand");
};

//This is what I have to do in order to make it work. 
document.getElementById("test_button_2").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("created_div").classList.toggle("container_expand");
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <style>
    /*This is the class that will be applied with the second button.*/
    
    .container_expand {
      position: absolute;
      top: 5%;
      left: 5%;
      width: 90%;
      height: 90%;
    }
    /*------------------*/
    
    .container {
      padding: 3px;
      margin: 10px;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: #bad4ff;
    }
  </style>

  <div class="container" id="test_button_1">Click me first to create a new class, a new div, and asign the created class to the created div.</div>
  <div class="container" id="test_button_2">Click me second to apply the "container_expand" class, which was on the css &lt;style&gt;&lt;/style&gt; tag sincethe begining.</div>

  <br>
  <br>
  <span id="test">Test</span>

</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, I have to make the animation process with two different buttons. When I try to put the code that each button excecutes in a single button, the animation doesn't take place and the div just instantly appears with the properties of the last class assigned to it.

Do you guys see any way of doing this with just one button? And just using javascript, not jQuery.

Thank you very very much!

Comment: To modify the contents of an internal style sheet, don't set the `.innerHTML` of the `style` element. Use the `styleSheets` property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is just an issue of the UI being updated with the final style faster than the duration of the animation.

Setting a short delay on the animation solves the problem.

```js
function expand(id) {

  //I first create a style element in which I'll be able to insert a new class that I'm going to create. This new class will be used to position the future div on top of the element whose id was provided as argument of this function.
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  style.type = 'text/css';
  var style_content = "";
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  var element_properties = element.getBoundingClientRect(); //Here I get the position of the element.

  //Now I describe the new class.
  style_content += ".container_inactive {"
    style_content += "box-sizing: border-box;";
    style_content += "position:absolute;";
    style_content += "top:" + element_properties.top + "px;";
    style_content += "left:" + element_properties.left + "px;*/";
    style_content += "padding:0px;";
    style_content += "margin:0px;";
    style_content += "border:solid;";
    style_content += "border-color:black;";
    style_content += "background-color:#40efbb;";
    style_content += "height:" + element_properties.height + "px;";
    style_content += "width:" + element_properties.width + "px;";
    style_content += "transition: all 0.5s;";
    style_content += "z-index:1;";
  style_content += "}";

  style.innerHTML = style_content; //I insert the previously described class inside the <style></style> tags.

  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style); //I insert the previously created style element inside the <head></head> tags.

  //Now I create the div
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.id = "created_div";
  div.className = "container_inactive"; //Here I assign the created class to the created div
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(div); //And instert the div in the body of the document
}

//------------This is just a random divisor------------------

document.getElementById("test_button_1").onclick = function() {
  expand("test"); //I excecute the script to create the class and the div, and assigning the style to the div.

  /*With the following line I would apply a DIFFERENT class to the div (and not the one created in the previous script), in order to make it transition to it. But here is where I run into troubles.
 If uncommented, the CSS Transition won't take place.
  If excecuted later by another button, the CSS does takes place as you can see in this snippet*/
  //document.getElementById("created_div").classList.toggle("container_expand");
  
  // Delay the animation by 50/1000 of a second:
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("created_div").classList.toggle("container_expand");
  }, 50);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <style>
    /*This is the class that will be applied with the second button.*/
    
    .container_expand {
      position: absolute;
      top: 5%;
      left: 5%;
      width: 90%;
      height: 90%;
    }
    /*------------------*/
    
    .container {
      padding: 3px;
      margin: 10px;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: #bad4ff;
    }
  </style>

  <div class="container" id="test_button_1">Just click me one time!</div>


  <br>
  <br>
  <span id="test">Test</span>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That works very well! I also reduced the delay, in order for it not to be noticeable during the animation. How much do you think I could bring down this delay in order for the animation to still work cross-browser/device? Thanks again!!

Comment: @FedericoGiancarelli you're welcome. I wouldn't bring it down less than 25 milliseconds. Don't forget to up vote the answer as well.

Comment: Yes, I did so! But it said that as I had a reputation under 15 they would save my vote and show it only when my reputation goes over 15 (I just created my account a few hours ago)